# What MySQL datatype to store a PHP DateInterval

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to store a PHP [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) in a MySQL database.

What is the best database datatype to use for this so that I can serialize the DateInterval? (i.e. I want to store it, then create a DateInterval from the database value later).

Comment: Why do you want to store a DateInterval; what is your usage?

Comment: not sure why you need it but if you want you can user varchar

Comment: @prodigitalson, so I can use it :-)  I want to add it to a DateTime.  In my application, a user gets to specify a date interval (i.e. every 35 days).  I need to persist this to the database.

Comment: Does the user get to specify the unit of time as well? I assume not, because you'd probably just store an int if it was always days or something like that, but thought it was worth asking.

Comment: Even if the user does specify the units - doesn't mean you can't just convert it to seconds before storing it in the database.

Comment: Do you want to store the PHP date interval format which can be used to create a date interval later? Maybe interesting? https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_date_interval_format.asp. Store it as a string?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I thought of that, but I'd prefer not to limit it to "days", in case at some point in the future the user needs to say "1 day, 24 minutes, 39 seconds".  Also, I was trying to make it as easy as possible at the application layer to add/subtract this interval to a DateTime.

Comment: @RyanVincent, yes, store a DateInterval so it can be used to create a DateInterval later.

Comment: Certainly there are different ways to do it, but I would go for varchar and store the interval specification that the constructor takes like "P35D", "P1DT24M39S", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest storing the interval specification that the `DateInterval` constructor takes, like "P35D", "P1DT24M39S", etc.

The reasons I'd choose this:

1. It's simple. If you're letting your user pick specific intervals, I assume you have a form with different inputs for the different units of time. It would be super simple to create one of those strings from input like that, rather than converting between time units to store an int.
2. It's relatively compact. Not as compact as if you *did* convert it to one unit of time and store it as an int, but much more compact than serializing the DateInterval object and storing the whole thing.

I may have overlooked a factor that would make something else a better choice, but I mainly just wanted to share the reasoning for my earlier comment.

---

If you aren't initially getting the interval directly from the user as I assumed, but instead from a `DateTime::diff` (or something else I haven't thought of), you can still get the interval spec from the object. It has public properties that store all the pieces you'd need. Something like this should work:

```
function getIntervalSpec(DateInterval $interval) {
    $spec = 'P';
    foreach(['y', 'm', 'd', 'h', 'i', 's'] as $u) {
        if ($u == 'h') $spec .= 'T';
        $spec .= $interval->$u;
        $spec .= $u == 'i' ? 'M' : strtoupper($u);
    }
    return $spec;
}
```

Comment: thanks!  The one reason I asked the question (which I haven't tested yet, but am getting close) is the `format()` method appears to require a format string?  If I don't pass a format string, will it pick the "best" one?  That would suit my needs perfectly if I could just `->format()` the DateInterval when serializing and then construct with the result string when constructing.

Comment: Well, since `format()` is really there to let you specify the output format, the format string isn't optional. I assumed you were starting with user input that you would use to create the DateInterval. If that's the case, I would store the interval spec before creating the object, rather than trying to get the interval spec back out of the object with `format()`. If that's _not_ the case, and you're creating the DateInterval using `DateTime::diff`, then I would create the interval spec string using the public properties of the DateInterval rather than `format()`.

Comment: @JoshPetitt I edited the answer with an example of a way to create an interval spec string from a DateInterval.

Comment: awesome!  I ended up using [CarbonInterval](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/CarbonInterval.php#L532) to automagically provide the spec() function.  I serialize using `spec()` and then can create the DateInterval using that spec string.

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize in `DateInterval`'s constructor format: `$interval->format("P%yY%mM%dDT%hH%iM%sS");`

But, there is pitfall. You can't restore `invert` (sign) or number of days `days` via constructor. This two properties initialized by `DateTime->diff(DateTime)` directly. If you don't need this information - `format` will be fine. But if you need it, `serialize($interval)` is the best option.

Comment: Good points here! `format` _is_ a much neater way to do it. And I hadn't considered invert either. If negative intervals are a concern, storing invert separately in a bool column and setting it after creating the object might still be better than storing the serialized object.